# two package in one AS file

Tags: actionscript-3

I am new in AS and I want to print md5 hash.

I have a package named "com.adobe.crypto" with class MD5.

```
package com.adobe.crypto {
    ...

    public class MD5 {
       ...
    }
}
```

I tried to print output by another package located to bottom of the document:

```
package {
  import com.adobe.crypto.*;
  public class hello extends Example {
    public function hello() {
      trace(MD5.hash("hello"));
    }
  }
}
```

but there is an error: "hello.as: Error: A file found in a source-path can not have more than one externally visible definition. com.adobe.crypto:MD5;hello"

there is a [link](http://wonderfl.net/c/nFDy).

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript (like Java) you can have one public class in an .as file. Also, that .as file must have the same name as the public class contained in it.

Secondly, to use MD5, you should use [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5.as?r=51), which is a library containing MD5 class.
What you have provided in the source is a decompiled version of MD5 class.

How, to include and external library would vary (from UI perspective) depending on what tool are you using for your project.